Designed GPS antenna for sim808 is not working
I'm trying to implement an active GPS antenna for my sim808 to integrate it into a PCB I'm working on it. For now, I use ordinary antennas from Amazon in my PCB. I'll attach its image. 
As I have never dealt with such antennas, I have no experience at all in designing such RF circuits. so I only copied the antenna schematic I bought from Amazon (reverse engineering). I'll attach the circuit I got the circuit I implemented.

But as a result, the GPS failed to fix a location. Could anyone please guide me? What am I missing?
As shown, I tested the circuit above but I got very very weak GPS signal. and at some places it cannot fix a location at all
Update:
This antenna also works for me. It is much easier to copy.


is it about the shielding..the grounding ??? any explanation

Any electrical part you buy from Amazon (including the instructions) can be very, very disappointing in terms of accuracy, performance, functionality, reliability, quality, repeatability, safety and documentation. This also applies to eBay, and all the other crappy sites like ali-express , bang-good etc.. Buy from reputable dealers may cost a bit more but, you get what you pay for and, in the longer run is cheaper (when you account for your time wasted).

Both ampifier outputs are shorted to ground with 100nF.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Raonoke i need to remove the 100nF? is this the only matter? i can try it

@Community WHAT EXXTRA INFO YOU NEED

@newdimension - Remove C17, C18. U15, U16=470p DC blocking caps. L6=7.5nH for best input return loss but 6.8nH works too. Use the same circuit and L/C values between RFOUT and RF IN of the two amplifiers. Use 470pF as a DC block between RFOUT of the 2nd amplifier and the 3.7dB PI-attenuator. Make Sure L4 (27nH) has a SRF>=1.6GHz. C4, C15, C16 =1nF would be already sufficient, 10nF is OK too. Additionally put 100pF in parallel with each of those caps. Pay extra attention to the PCB layout, you are dealing here with almost 40dB gain @ 1.56GHz.

@Raonoke thank you for your time, unfortunately, L4 SRF is 400 Mhz so I need to build another circuit this one cannot be modified

@Raonoke could you please provide the simplest circuit that would work for me? this one looks very complicated. I found some GPS using only 3...4 components ( IC+ 2..3 caps)

i uploaded an updated image in my post

The GNSS receiver modules should basically work with a passive antenna.
If you want an LNA on a board that also contains an LTE transceiver, you probably need to heavily filter the LNA's input, using a ceramic bandpass filter or two. Better yet, put the GNSS antenna on a cable and if you need an LNA, build that into the antenna, not the same board that contains your multi-function radio module.
For the simplest possible LNA topologies, check some datasheets and appnotes of SiGe transistor series (e.g. Infineon BFP series) or any MMIC LNA chip family for the GNSS L-band. Such as the chips that you're using. The datasheets or appnotes of these parts typically contain a minimalistic example schematic, along with detailed instructions on board routing and component selection.
If you venture into this territory, I would expect you to understand that blocking your microwave signal path to GND by MLCC's is not exactly conventional practice :-) although I have to admit that those 100nF caps possibly are not that much good at 1.6 GHz, having a resonant frequency quite a bit lower... is this a cunning trick by any chance? :-) Hmm. Checking this out using KSIM, the impedance seems like 5 Ohms at 1.6 GHz... doesn't seem like a cunning trick to me.
